# Convergence of the series $\frac1{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\frac1{n^n}$ converges or diverges .

By comparison test I can claim that $\frac1{n^n} < \frac1n$ , and since series $\frac1n$ appears divergent , so the series $\frac1{n^n}$ also diverges.
However by Cauchy root test the limit of $\frac1{n^n}$ appears to be $0<1$ which suggests the convergence of the series

Comment: A series of nonnegative terms with all terms greater than or equal to a divergent series diverges. To dramatize your error, consider the series with all terms equal to zero. By your logic, since $0 < 1/n$ for all $n$, it would diverge.

Comment: Your argument would be valid if $1/n^n \color{red}{>} 1/n$. But it is not.

Comment: Series $\dfrac{1}{n^n}$ converges so quickly that just adding $5$ terms gives the result with $4$ exact decimals. Adding $10$ terms gives $1.29128\,599706$ which has eleven exact decimals

Comment: @Raffaele: quite right, anyway shouldn't leave the OP the impression that this is a proof. What about $1/n^{n(20-n)}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot conclude that since $\frac{1}{n^n} < \frac{1}{n}$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$ diverges.

If $\frac{1}{n^n} > \frac{1}{n}$ (which is not true), then we can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$ diverges.

You have used Cauchy root test to conclude that it converges.

If we want to use comparison test, notice that $$\frac{1}{n^n} \leq\frac{1}{n^2}$$

and since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ conveges, hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^n}$ converges.

Comment: Then is it that this given series converges by Cauchy root test ?

Comment: yes, you have proven it using the root test.

Comment: Now suppose if I use Ratio Test then, let u(n)=1/n^n  and so u(n+1)=1/(n+1)^(n+1). Hence u(n)/u(n+1)=(1+1/n)^n * (n+1) and thus taking limit n tends to infinity on the above I get infinity(not sure whether calculations are correct) , which stands as greater than 1. So can I claim , the series in convergent by Ratio Test.

Comment: Usually for ratio test, we compute $\left| \frac{u(n+1)}{u(n)}\right|$ and show that it is less than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison test tells you that if $$a_n> b_n$$ and $$\sum_{n}a_n$$ **converges**, then $$\sum_n b_n$$ **also converges**.

It does **not** say that if $\sum_{n} a_n$ diverges then $\sum_{n} b_n$ diverges. If it did, then because $\frac{1}{2^n} < 1$, you could conclude that $\sum \frac1{2^n}$ also diverges.

In fact, you would need the inequality reversed, so if $a_n<b_n$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\sum b_n$ also diverges.

So, your logic is incorrect.

---

In fact, the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^n}$ **converges** by the comparison test with $\frac{1}{2^n}$ or with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Does it appear convergent or divergent ? How gonna I check it ?

Comment: @Nabendra I really really dislike users that don't read my answers before they ask questions about them.

Comment: I didn't understood your answer , as if I use 1/n the it diverges by comparison test instead of 1/n^2 or 1/2^n

Comment: @Nabendra You didn't understand my answer because you didn't bother reading it to the end. So I don't see why I should bother helping you any further.

Comment: I do apologise, for my deed

Answer (score 0):

A series converges if it has a converging *upper* bound and it diverges if it has a diverging *lower* bound. In other cases, you cannot conclude.

In this particular case, you can for instance exploit

$$\frac1{n^n}\le \frac1{2^n}$$ for $n\ge2$. Actually, the sequence converges extremely quickly, *super-exponentially*.